# Fallback condition on custom date event

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

need a little help to correct my fallback conditions here. I have 3 different tab events, happening, upcoming and expired. this current code I have here is set to "happening event" and facing difficulty to understand how or where to position the fallback if there is "no current happening event". if i create fallback condition it end up to duplicate the message of "No Current Events Set". Where should I need to place the condition to make the fallback not duplicating its message.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="happening">
<?php
  if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    // Check event record from ACF
    while ( have_rows('dtl') ) : the_row();
      $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_sub_field('event_date'));
      $dateA = $date->format('Y-m-d');
      $dateB = date('Y-m-d');
    endwhile; 

    // Compare event record from ACF & current date
    if (strtotime($dateA) == strtotime($dateB)) :
  ?>
  <section class="section-contents"><?php get_template_part( 'templates/events', 'query' ); ?></section>
  <?php else : // fallback if there's no active date ?>
  <section class="section-contents"> <h5 class="text-center text-danger text-uppercase">No Current Events Set</h5> </section>
  <?php endif; // close strtotime
  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had your else condition inside the loop, which means it would output your message for every iteration that your time comparision failed on. You need to move it outside the loop

```
 $x=false;
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    // Check event record from ACF
    while ( have_rows('dtl') ) : the_row();
      $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_sub_field('event_date'));
      $dateA = $date->format('Y-m-d');
      $dateB = date('Y-m-d');
    endwhile; 

    // Compare event record from ACF & current date
    if (strtotime($dateA) == strtotime($dateB)) :
        $x= true;
     ?>
        <section class="section-contents"><?php get_template_part( 'templates/events', 'query' ); ?></section>
  <?php endif; // close if strtotime... 
        endwhile;
  ?>
  <?php endif; // close if statement 
  wp_reset_postdata(); 
  if(!$x){ ?>
  <section class="section-contents"> <h5 class="text-center text-danger text-uppercase">No Current Events Set</h5> </section>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: the "else :" seems not connecting to the date condition since you end it... and this is my problem since yesterday... my issue here is the date if there's no current date active, it should fall to my message.

Comment: no it wouldnt, your post was a little confusing. I've updated a method above

Comment: ok I'm sorry if it is confusing. however, your updated method already works to my question. thank you very much for saving me here. appreciate it @David